# Creating a previous button and a reset

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello so I have this gallery with the images in an array. I also have a button that when clicked, it'll go to the next image. I tried to recreate a button that goes to the previous image, but when clicked, nothing happens.

Issue: Previous button does not work and cannot reset back to image 1 when pressing the next button upon getting to the final picture.

```
var imgArray = new Array();

imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src = './images/andrea_highres.jpg';

imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = './images/lizbeth_highres.jpg';

imgArray[2] = new Image();
imgArray[2].src = './images/lizzy_highres.jpg';

imgArray[3] = new Image();
imgArray[3].src = './images/nick_highres.jpg';

function nextImage(element) {
    var img = document.getElementById(element);

    for(var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
        if(imgArray[i].src == img.src) {
            if(i === imgArray.length) {
                document.getElementById(element).src = imgArray[0].src;
                break;
            }
            document.getElementById(element).src = imgArray[i+1].src;
            break;
        }
    }
}

function prevImage(element) {
    var img = document.getElementById(element);

    for(var i = 0; i > imgArray.length; i++) {
        if(imgArray[i].src == img.src) {
            if(i === imgArray.length) {
                document.getElementById(element).src = imgArray[0].src;
                break;
            }
            document.getElementById(element).src = imgArray[i-1].src;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do a `console.log(document.getElementById(element).src)` to verify it's value is relative or absolute

Comment: `if(i === imgArray.length)` is impossible

Comment: @MisterJojo    Console.log gives me the current file name. if it's on image 1, it'll give image 1 + however many times I press the previous button

Comment: 1- you mean the current file path ? 2- is it relative or absolute ?

Comment: It comes out absolute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code should be OK .. (?)

```js
const imgRefs  = ['andrea', 'lizbeth', 'lizzy', 'nick']
  ,   imgArray = imgRefs.map( img =>  
        {
        let img = new Image()
        img.src = `./images/${img}_highres.jpg`
        return img  
        })
  ,   imageElement = document.getElementById('image_ID')  // make it as a const !
  ;
function changeImg( direction )
  {
  let newIndex = imgRefs.findIndex(x=>imageElement.src.includes(x) ) + direction

  if (newIndex < 0)               newIndex = 0
  if (newIndex >= imgRefs.length) newIndex = imgRefs.length -1

  imageElement.src = imgArray[newIndex].src
  }
function nextImage()
  {
  changeImg(+1)
  }
function prevImage()
  {
  changeImg(-1)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try with it

```
const imgArray = ['andrea', 'lizbeth', 'lizzy', 'nick'].map(img=>
  {
  let img = new Image()
  img.src = `./images/${img}_highres.jpg`
  return img  
  })

function nextImage(element) {
    changePicture(element, 1)
}

function prevImage(element) {
    changePicture(element, -1)
}

function changePicture(element, count){
    var img = document.getElementById(element),
        index = imgArray.findIndex(el => el.src == img.src);
    if(index + count <= -1) { 
        img.src = imgArray[imgArray.length-1].src;
    }else if(index + count >= imgArray.length){ // You will never reach the length. The length value is last pos index + 1 (if we have 4 element, last index will be 3 but length woill be 4)
        img.src = imgArray[0].src;
    }else{
        img.src = imgArray[i + count].src;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to work although it will not cycle through the 2 images in the middle. Click Next on the default image will do nothing, while clicking the Previous button will take me to the last image but no further.